# How to set slippage tollerance in while integrating swap feature of router of uniswap

Tags: ethers.js, uniswap, router

const amountOutMin = ethers.utils.parseUnits((box2Input * (1 - tolerance / 100)).toString(), decimals1);

When I am keeping the slippage low I am getting a gas estimation error and when keeping it very high almost 100% then my transaction is working. And when I try to use this with the parseUnits then it gives underflow error. I have searched it everywhere but not getting a solution.